# Android GraphView setGridStyle() method not found

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I am using the `GraphView` component available here:
http://android-graphview.org/

As per their documentation, such method should exist:

```
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setGridStyle(GridStyle.HORIZONTAL);
```

to change the style of the grid.

However i can't find this method when i try to use it. All of the others are there.
The library version i am using: `GraphView-3.1.1.jar`

Any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/commit/1d10ceabe8cc477fe8440b18e197192decbb4ad6) the method was only introduced yesterday. However the .jar file you're using is 4 months old.
You can now either:

- build the jar yourself
- include the code into your project
- wait for jjoe64 to update the jar file